# Assigning value from DateTime to a nullable DateTime always gives kind 'Unspecified' instead of 'Utc'

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datamember

I am trying to pass a value from a DateTime object to a DateTime? one as in the example. However, the kind always remains unspecified and is not passed to Utc as in the original object. What should I do differently?

If I try something like the following it works, so it must be related to being a DataMember:

```
DateTime? start = null;
DateTime departureDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
start = departureDate;
```

However, in the following example, the kind property of the nullable DateTime object remains 'Unspecified':

```
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartDate 
    {
        get { return _startDate; }
        set
        {
            if (_startDate!= value)
            {
                ChangeTracker.RecordOriginalValue("StartDate", _startDate);
                _startDate= value;
                OnPropertyChanged("StartDate");
            }
        }
    }
    private Nullable<System.DateTime> _startDate;

    public DateTime ESTIMATED_DATE_DEPARTURE { get; set; }
```

---

```
clientOrder.StartDate =  order.WAGON_TRSP_ORDER.WAGON.ESTIMATED_DATE_DEPARTURE;
```

Comment: Apart from the UtcNow I don't see anything in this code which would change/set the kind. You can use [DateTime.SpecifyKind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.specifykind?view=netframework-4.8) if you want to set it manually but I don't know if this answers your question.

Comment: The problem is that I receive the DateTime value from an exterior source and nothing assures me that they will always send the information in Utc, even though they do now

Comment: Where is ESTIMATED_DATE_DEPARTURE coming from exactly?

Comment: Well if you parse a DateTime it will always be Unspecified as far as I know. If you know they only send UTC you can parse it manually (refer to my comment from 5 min ago). Maybe this is what you need.

Comment: Then you have a serialization issue, nothing to do with nullability or anything. Most formats have no way at all to specify if a date/time value is local, UTC or anything else. If a time zone is explicitly included, you can try deserializing to a `DateTimeOffset`, but otherwise you will inevitably have to make some assumption yourself.

Comment: @Isma The problem is not from the incoming ESTIMATED_DATE_DEPARTURE as this comes as UTC from a .json file using [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC))

Comment: Is the Kind specified on that or is just the saved time (JSON) in utc? Usually parsers don't decide on a kind so it could be undefined. Once again you'd use DateTime.SpecifyKind to change it to utc yourself.

Comment: @Joelius [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm) does deserialize and the ESTIMATED_DATE_DEPARTURE is indeed in UTC. The problem here is that it does not pass that property to the left side property clientOrder.StartDate

Comment: What happens when you put a breakpoint on the line "_startDate= value;" and hover over value? What kind does it have? If it's utc the problem could actually be the DataMember. Also does anything change if you then step one further? What value does _startDate have then?